# Dynamic Subdomain For Every User In AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

What I'm trying to do is a service that for every subdomain typed it shows the content of an S3 bucket subfolder.

The behavior should be:

```
user1.app.mydomain.com => app.mydomain.com/user1
user2.app.mydomain.com => app.mydomain.com/user2
user3.app.mydomain.com => app.mydomain.com/user3
...
```

I tried to setup an API in API Gateway linked to a Lambda Function, but it seems that it can't work with wildcards.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: How about [Serving a multitude of static sites from a wildcard domain in AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49817210/1695906)?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yeah it could be – but it's not clear how to configure the Cloudfront distribution in order to use the Lambda function.