# How to point wildcard domain (*.example.com) to s3 buckets with cloudfront/route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have SSL Certified and setup a homepage for my site: example.com and www.example.com using Cloudfront, Route 53, and an s3 bucket. The site is just a basic static site.

I am trying to setup my Cloudfront/Route 53 to allow for WildCard subomdains so I can create some landing pages eg, industry-a.example.com, industry-z.example.com and have them point to separate static s3 buckets.

I have tried adding in *.example.com to my Cloudfront and Route 53

I have a hosted zone created for a domain from namecheap in Route 53 with the following records:

```
Type        Name                Target
A Record     -> example.com     -> My.cloudfront.net
A Record     -> www.example.com -> My.cloudfront.net
CNAME Record -> *.example.com   -> s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com.
```

In my CloudFront distribution configuration:

Alternate domains set to:

```
example.com
www.example.com
*.example.com
```

Domain Name:

```
My.cloudfront.net
```

Origin ID:

```
example.com.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: First, I'd like to clarify: why are you trying to do this with just one CloudFront distribution, instead of one for each subdomain?  There is no cost or performance benefit I can think of, and the two alternative solutions that come to mind will increase complexity and cost, as well as creating security issues (unused/vacant subdomain hijacking) if not deployed with caution, a full understanding of their implications, and certain mitigations.

Comment: Note also that your existing wildcard CNAME record pointing directly to S3 is also a hijacking risk.  I could create a bucket named `any-subdomain-you-have-no-bucket-for.example.com` in us-east-2 and impersonate one of your subdomains.

Comment: Thanks Michael, 
This was before I had read your comment suggesting to run multiple cloudfront distributions. I'll try that now

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I've got it working now thanks to your advice for creating separate distributions! I am now trying to add the aws cli command to my script so that it can create a distribution after it creates the s3 bucket. How can I set the SSL cert with the aws cli for my cloudfront distribution? Setting it manually in the gui is a lot of clicking around. My line is as follows `aws cloudfront -create-distribution \ --viewer-protocol-policy --redirect-to-https \ --origin-domain-name $LOCATION_NAME.example.io.s3.amazonaws.com \ --default-root-object index.html `

Comment: You should also checkout this resource based on to set SSL on AWS CloudFront and S3 (https://bryce.fisher-fleig.org/blog/setting-up-ssl-on-aws-cloudfront-and-s3/) I hope it will help you definitely.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Dana it was helpful. I have everything working now as Michael had suggested spinning up a separate cloudfront distribution for each bucket. Only problem I am having is creating the distribution with the cli

Comment: It's my pleasure.