# Point subfolder in S3 bucket to *.buildmywebsite domain

Tags: amazon-s3

Lets say that I have an S3 bucket called `apps.buildmysite.com` for my hypothetical website `buildmysite.com` (I also have `buildmysite.com` and `www.buildmysite.com` as S3 buckets which host the main website).

Inside the S3 bucket is a list of folders:

- `app-2343242`
- `app-9402932`

Each app corresponds to a separate website. I now want to create the corresponding subdomains for the above folders. So in effect:

- `app-2343242` -> `http://apps.buildmysite.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/app-2343242`
- `app-9402932` -> `http://apps.buildmysite.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/app-9402932`

So when someone visits `app-2343242.buildmysite.com`, they are served a file residing at `http://apps.buildmysite.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/app-2343242/index.html`.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: You can't do this with S3 alone, because it does not have the necessary configurability -- you need a reverse proxy with header rewrite capabilities in conjunction with S3.   I'm marking this as a duplicate of [Serving a multitude of static sites from a wildcard domain in AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49812706/1695906), where I explained how CloudFront and Lambda@Edge can accomplish this.

Comment: Hi Michael, yes I managed to fix it with your instructions. Thank you very much!

Comment: I am having another issue though - discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59598350/lambda-script-to-direct-to-fallback-s3-domain-subfolder-when-not-found. It's to do with creating a fallback approach whenever a S3 domain subfolder is not found.